# Using leaflet with arcgis map

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, esri, arcmap

I've been using arc maps but now trying to just play around with this leaflet script files.  I'm getting an undefined basemap error and not exactly sure where its coming from.  Following all the examples to a t and still the error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the example i've been following https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet

Here is the code:

```
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>    
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="lib/esri-leaflet/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //basemap
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.75, -122.45], 12);

    L.esri.basemapLayer("Gray").addTo(map);

    L.esri.featureLayer("http://gis.chmuraecon.com/arcgis/rest/services/jobseq/Demographics/MapServer/1", {

    }).addTo(map);


</script>
```

Comment: Looks like that should work.  Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) replicating the problem?  That will help if there is something else getting in the way.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the error by providing a bad link to the esri-leaflet.js file.  Open that file and replace the contents of your esri-leaflet.js file with the contents found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/master/examples/lib/esri-leaflet/esri-leaflet-src.js)